# Basemap Matplotlib Colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am using matplotlib and basemap to generate a map of the USA and color states by population. I can get the map to display and states colored by population (using the 'hot' color scale), but I'm having trouble when trying to also display a color bar. Here's how I'm displaying the map and coloring states:

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-121,llcrnrlat=20,urcrnrlon=-62,urcrnrlat=51,projection='lcc',lat_1=32,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)

shp_info = m.readshapefile('st99_d00','states',drawbounds=True)

colors={}
statenames=[]
cmap = plt.cm.hot
vmin = 0
vmax = 100000000 
for shapedict in m.states_info:
    statename = shapedict['NAME']
    # skip DC and Puerto Rico.
    if statename not in ['District of Columbia','Puerto Rico']:
        stateabbrev = conversiondict2[statename]
        rate = statedict[stateabbrev]
        colors[statename] = cmap(1.-np.sqrt((rate-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)))[:3]
    statenames.append(statename)

ax = plt.gca()

for nshape,seg in enumerate(m.states):
    # skip DC and Puerto Rico.
    if statenames[nshape] not in ['Puerto Rico', 'District of Columbia']:
        color = rgb2hex(colors[statenames[nshape]])
    # Offset Alaska and Hawaii to the lower left corner. 
        if statenames[nshape] == 'Alaska': 
            seg = list(map(lambda (x,y): (0.35*x + 1100000, 0.35*y-1300000), seg))
        elif statenames[nshape] == 'Hawaii':
            seg = list(map(lambda (x,y): (x + 5100000, y-1400000), seg))
        poly = Polygon(seg,facecolor=color,edgecolor="black",zorder=0)
        ax.add_patch(poly)

m.colorbar(cmap, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Note I left out my state and abbreviation conversion dictionaries for brevity. This displays fine without the m.colorbar(cmap, ax=ax) line, but when i try to add the colorbar I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

Maybe I don't fully understand how the Basemap colorbar function works, but I thought that in my case cmap would be the mappable argument (the color gradient) and ax would be the axis limits? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out [Plotly Choropleth Plots](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/)?

Comment: I haven't. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!